# SVG gooey effect not working on the latest version of FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have an issue where my feGuassian blur is not working properly when using any other color than black.

On chrome it works perfectly. I have not tested on safari yet.

[image]

I have created an example on jsFiddle :

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="bigLogo">
    <div class="blobs">
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="blob"></div>
    <div class="connect12">
        <div class="part1"></div>
        <div class="part2"></div>
        <div class="part3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="connect23">
        <div class="part3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="connect31">
        <div class="part3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www,w3.org" version='1.1'>
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0                                                                                       0 1 0 0 0                                                                                   0 0 1 0 0                                                                                   0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
</div>
</div>

<div class="break">
<div class="smallLogo">
        <div class="blobs">
            <div class="blob"></div>
            <div class="blob"></div>
            <div class="blob"></div>
            <div class="connect12">
                <div class="part1"></div>
                <div class="part2"></div>
                <div class="part3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="connect23">
                <div class="part3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="connect31">
                <div class="part3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <svg xmlns="http://www,w3.org" version='1.1'>
            <defs>
                <filter id="goo2">
                    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur"/>
                    <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                                                   0 0 0 0 0
                                                                   0 0 0 0 0
                                                                   0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo"/>
                    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotate-logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-logo-small {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.3);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.3);
    }
}

@keyframes rotate-logo-small {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.3);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.3);
        transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.3);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blob-anim-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(6px) translateY(10px);
        transform: translateX(6px) translateY(10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-43px) translateY(25px);
        transform: translateX(-43px) translateY(25px);
    }
}

@keyframes blob-anim-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-43px) translateY(25px);
        transform: translateX(-43px) translateY(25px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blob-anim-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(59px) translateY(-61px);
        transform: translateX(59px) translateY(-61px);
    }
}

@keyframes blob-anim-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(59px) translateY(-61px);
        transform: translateX(59px) translateY(-61px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blob-anim-top-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(28px) translateY(36px);
        transform: translateX(28px) translateY(36px);
    }
}

@keyframes blob-anim-top-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(28px) translateY(36px);
        transform: translateX(28px) translateY(36px);
    }
}

@keyframes line-anim-con12 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-37deg) translateX(-37px) translateY(-83px);
        transform: rotate(-37deg) translateX(-37px) translateY(-83px);
        width: 120px;
    }
}

@keyframes line-anim-con23 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        height: 1px;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(13deg) translateX(19px) translateY(-46px);
        transform: rotate(13deg) translateX(19px) translateY(-46px);
        height: 25px;
    }
}

@keyframes line-anim-con31 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        transform: translateX(-30px) translateY(-24px);
        width: 1px;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-46px) translateY(8px) rotate(25deg);
        transform: translateX(-46px) translateY(8px) rotate(25deg);
        width: 23px;
    }
}

.bigLogo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 208.8px;
    height: 208.8px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.smallLogo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    .blobs{
        -webkit-filter: url('#goo2') !important;
        filter: url('#goo2') !important;
        -webkit-animation: rotate-logo ease-in-out 9s infinite alternate !important;
        animation: rotate-logo ease-in-out 9s infinite alternate !important;
        .blob{
            background: #000 !important;
        }
        .part1{
            background-color: #000 !important;
        }
        .part2{
            background-color: #000 !important;
        }
        .part3{
            background-color: #000 !important;
        }
    }
}

.blobs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 208.8px;
    height: 208.8px;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-filter: url('#goo');
    filter: url('#goo');
    -webkit-animation: rotate-logo ease-in-out 9s infinite alternate;
    animation: rotate-logo ease-in-out 9s infinite alternate;
}

.blob {
    background: #2a4059;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.blob:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: blob-anim-left ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: blob-anim-left ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
}

.blob:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: blob-anim-right ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: blob-anim-right ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;

}

.blob:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: blob-anim-top-right ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: blob-anim-top-right ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
}

.line{
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 150px;
    position: relative;
    filter: url('#goo');

}

.part1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2a4059;
    transform: perspective(70px) rotateY(50deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.part2{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #2a4059;
    transform: perspective(70px) rotateY(-50deg);
}

.part3{
    background: #2a4059;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.connect12{
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    -webkit-animation: line-anim-con12 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: line-anim-con12 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    .part3{
        height: 78% !important;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        position: absolute;
    }
}

.connect23{
    width: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    -webkit-animation: line-anim-con23 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: line-anim-con23 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
}

.connect31{
    height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    -webkit-animation: line-anim-con31 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
    animation: line-anim-con31 ease-in-out 2.5s infinite alternate;
}

.break{
    position: relative;
    top: 350px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lastgiven/kqmabvxs/2/

If anyone could have a look and see if they could help me with the issue I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to see here that would indicate that something is not working.

Comment: On the new version of firefox the grey logo has white pieces during the animation of the gooey effect where on chrome it is working perfectly.

Comment: We need the element to be a solid color.

Comment: It does not display with white pieces for me on Firefox 57 on a Mac.

Comment: Please reference to the screenshots uploaded above

Comment: I don't see that when I run the jsfiddle. What version of Firefox on what platform are you using?

Comment: Tested on a mac as well seems that it is working on mac but not on windows.

Comment: Raise a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Graphics) with a minimal testcase as an attachment.

Comment: Thanks busy doing it now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "gooey effect" seems to have been made popular through [this post on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/). While it describes very nicely how it works, it fails to explore the different possibilities SVG filters offer to formulate the filter. It seems that different implementations of the filter primitives and application on elements in the SVG or HTML namespace currently make differences in rendering across browsers.

Let me first explain the possibilities and then present a test case for cross-browser comparisons.

**Bluring the input grafics**

The filter starts with

```
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" />
```

to produce a blurred image. While it "smears" different colors, its main intent here is to produce a wide band of pixels along the border of the grafic sources where the alpha color values vary. The further you go out, the more partial transparency increases.

**Raising the contrast of the alpha channel**

The original idea takes advantage of the `feColorMatrix` primitive:

```
<feColorMatrix mode="matrix"
               values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9"
               result="cutoff" />
```

This has the obvious disadvantage of nobody understanding what these numbers mean. In theory, there is a mathematically identical version using the `feComponentTransfer` primitive:

```
<feComponentTransfer result="cutoff">
    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="19" intercept="-9" />
</feComponentTransfer>
```

They both transform the alpha value of a RGBA color with the function

```
(alpha) => slope * alpha + intercept
```

and clamp the result to the interval [0, 1], so that

```
alpha < (0 - intercept) / slope => 0
alpha > (1 - intercept) / slope => 1
```

There is a small range of input alphas that get transformed to partial transparency in the output. (For values 19 and -9 it is between 0.46...0.54.) The effect is of reducing the wide blurry borders to a very slim line that now "softens" all corners and has that "gooey" effect between nearby source objects.

But why leave that slim band of partial transparency in the output? It is possible to define a hard distinction between fully opaque and fully transparent:

```
<feComponentTransfer result="cutoff">
  <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1" />
</feComponentTransfer>
```

The range of input values is halved:

```
alpha <  0.5 => 0
alpha >= 0.5 => 1
```

This can result in visible antialiasing artefacts. There might be an advantage in a very small blurring of the result:

```
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1" />
</feComponentTransfer>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="cutoff" />
```

**Superimposing the original grafics**

To avoid the "smearing" of different colors inside an object you can superimpose the original on the "goo". There are several filter primitives, some with parameters that can achieve that. Basic superimposition can be formulated as

```
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="cutoff" />
// or
<feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="cutoff" />
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
</feMerge>
// or
<feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic" in2="cutoff" />
```

Restricting the superimposition to the "goo" area can be achieved with

```
<feComposite operator="atop" in="SourceGraphic" in2="cutoff" />
```

**Rendering results**

In theory, apart from that last distinction, the results should look the same. I've designed a test case where you can play around with the different filters and their setting. The filters can be applied to SVG circles and rectangles, or to HTML divs. You can compare the effect on multi-colored and monochrome objects. This should help to find a filter that has optimal cross-browser consistency.

```js
const filters = new (function () {
    const fBlur = d3.selectAll('feGaussianBlur:first-child');
    const pBlur = d3.select('feComponentTransfer + feGaussianBlur');
    const fFunc = d3.select('feFuncA[type=linear]');
    const fMatr = d3.select('feColorMatrix');
    let fComp = d3.selectAll('feComposite');
    let active;

    const ids = {
        fcd: '#component-discrete',
        fcl: '#component-linear',
        fmx: '#colormatrix'
    };
    const xmls = new XMLSerializer();
    const pre = d3.select('pre');

    this.activate = function (a) {
        active = ids[a];
        this.showSource();
    };

    this.showSource = function () {
        const source = xmls.serializeToString(d3.select(active).node())
          .replace(/>\s*</g, '><')
          .replace(/<fe/g, '\n<fe')
          .replace(/(<\/\w+>)(<\/\w+>)/g, '$1\n$2')
          .replace(/(<feFuncA|<feMergeNode)/g, '    $1')
          .trim()
        pre.text(source);
    };

    this.blur = function (deviation) {
        fBlur.attr('stdDeviation', deviation);
        this.showSource();
    };

    this.postBlur = function (deviation) {
        pBlur.attr('stdDeviation', deviation);
        this.showSource();
    };

    this.contrast = function (slope, intercept) {
        fFunc.attr('slope', slope)
            .attr('intercept', intercept);
        fMatr.attr('values', [
            "1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0", 
            slope, 
            intercept
        ].join(' '));
        this.showSource();
    };

    this.combinate = function (operator) {
        fComp.remove();
        switch (operator) {
        case 'none':
            return this.showSource();
        case 'merge':
            fComp = d3.selectAll('filter')
                .append('feMerge');
            fComp.append('feMergeNode')
                .attr('in', "cutoff");
            fComp.append('feMergeNode')
                .attr('in', "SourceGraphic");
            return this.showSource();
        case 'blend':
            fComp = d3.selectAll('filter')
                .append('feBlend');
            break;
        default:
            fComp = d3.selectAll('filter')
                .append('feComposite')
                .attr('operator', operator);
            break;
        }
        fComp.attr('in', "SourceGraphic")
            .attr('in2', "cutoff");
        this.showSource();
    };
})();

const tweaks = new (function () {
    this.blur = d3.select('#blur-select');
    const check = d3.select('#blur-select input');
    this.linear = d3.select('#linear-select');
    const selects = d3.selectAll('#linear-select input');
    const slope = selects.filter('#slope');
    const intercept = selects.filter('#intercept');
    const visSlope = d3.select('#visSlope');

    this.activate = function (active) {
        this.blur.classed('inactive', active !== 'fcd');
        check.property('disabled', active !== 'fcd');
        this.linear.classed('inactive', active === 'fcd');
        selects.property('disabled', active === 'fcd');
    };

    this.limit = function () {
        const min = 1 - slope.property('value');
        intercept.attr('min', min);
        if (min > intercept.property('value')) {
            intercept.property('value', min);
        }
        return [
            slope.property('value'), 
            intercept.property('value')
        ];
    };

    this.visualize = function (slope, intercept) {
        visSlope.attr('x1', -intercept * 100 / slope)
            .attr('x2', (1 - intercept) * 100 / slope);
    };
})();

const primitives = d3.selectAll('.primitive');
const examples =  d3.selectAll('.example');
const goo = d3.selectAll('.goo');

d3.selectAll('input[name=variant]').on('change', function () {
    if (!this.checked) return;
    examples.classed('hide', true)
        .filter(this.id).classed('hide', false);
}).dispatch('change');

d3.select('#color').on('change', function () {
    primitives.classed('bw', this.checked);
}).dispatch('change');

d3.select('#filter-select').on('change', function () {
    goo.attr('class', 'goo ' + this.value);
    filters.activate(this.value);
    tweaks.activate(this.value);
}).dispatch('change');

d3.select('#deviation').on('input change', function () {
    d3.select('#devNum').text(this.value);
    filters.blur(this.value);
}).dispatch('change');

tweaks.blur.on('change', function () {
    filters.postBlur(this.checked ? 1 : 0);
}).dispatch('change');

tweaks.linear.on('change', function () {
    const params = tweaks.limit();
    tweaks.visualize.apply(tweaks, params);
    filters.contrast.apply(filters, params);
}).dispatch('change');

d3.select('#combine-select').on('change', function (e) {
  filters.combinate(this.value);
}).dispatch('change');

function tweenFactory (forth) {
    return function () {
        let interpolator;
        const node = this,
            from = forth ? 0 : 500,
            to   = forth ? 500 : 0;
        if (this instanceof SVGElement) {
            interpolator = d3.interpolateTransformSvg(
                'translate(0, ' + from + ')',
                'translate(0, ' + to + ')'
            );
            return function (t) {
                node.setAttribute("transform", interpolator(t));
            };
        } else {
            interpolator = d3.interpolateTransformCss(
                'translate(0px, ' + from + 'px)',
                'translate(0px, ' + to + 'px)'
            );
            return function (t) {
                node.style.transform = interpolator(t);
            };
        }
    };
}

d3.selectAll('.move').transition()
    .on('start', function repeat () {
        d3.active(this)
            .duration(2000)
            .ease(d3.easeSinInOut)
            .tween('forth', tweenFactory(true))
        .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .ease(d3.easeSinInOut)
            .tween('back', tweenFactory(false))
        .transition()
            .on('start', repeat);
    });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
input[type=number] {
  width: 3em;
}
#vis {
   fill:none;
   stroke:black;
   margin-left:10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
pre {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 10em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.floating {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.floating.example {
   width: 250px;
   height: 400px;
}
div.goo {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   height: 800px;
   transform: scale(0.5);
   transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
div.goo div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
div.goo .move {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.bw {
  fill: black;
  background: black !important;
}
.fcd {
  filter: url(#component-discrete);
}
.fcl {
  filter: url(#component-linear);
}
.fmx {
  filter: url(#colormatrix);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="floating" height="0" width="0">
  <filter id="colormatrix" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="800">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" />
    <feColorMatrix mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="cutoff" />
    <feComposite operator="atop" in="SourceGraphic" in2="cutoff" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="component-linear" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="800">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" />
    <feComponentTransfer result="cutoff">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="19" intercept="-9" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feComposite operator="atop" in="SourceG forraphic" in2="cutoff" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="component-discrete" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="800">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" />
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feGaussianBlur id="post-blur" stdDeviation="1" result="cutoff" />
    <feComposite operator="atop" in="SourceGraphic" in2="cutoff" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="floating example" viewBox="0 0 500 800">
  <g class="goo fcd">
    <circle class="primitive" r="100" cx="150" cy="400" fill="#ff0000" />
    <circle class="primitive" r="100" cx="350" cy="400" fill="#00ff00" />
    <rect class="primitive move" x="170" y="70" width="160" height="160" fill="#0000ff" />
  </g>
</svg>

<div class="floating example hide">
<div class="goo fcd">
  <div class="primitive" style="background:#ff0000;left:50px;top:300px"></div>
  <div class="primitive" style="background:#00ff00;right:50px;top:300px"></div>
  <div class="primitive move" style="background:#0000ff;left:170px;top:70px"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <p>Filtered Objects
  <input name="variant" id="svg" type="radio" checked="checked"></input><label>SVG primitives</label>
  <input name="variant" id="div" type="radio"></input><label>HTML divs</label></p>

  <p><input id="color" type="checkbox"></input>
  <label>Set black and white</label></p>

  <p><label>Blur value</label><br/>
  <input id="deviation" type="range" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="20"></input>
  <span id="devNum">20</span></p>

  <p><label>Cutoff Filter</label><br/>
  <select id="filter-select">
    <option value="fcd" selected="selected">Component/discrete</option>
    <option value="fcl">Component/linear</option>
    <option value="fmx">ColorMatrix</option>
  </select></p>

  <p id="blur-select"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></input>
  <label>Post-Blur for discrete</label></p>

  <p id="linear-select"><label>slope</label> <input id="slope" type="number" min="2" step="1" value="19"></input>
  <label>intercept</label> <input id="intercept" type="number" min="-18" max="0" step="1" value="-9"></input> for linear
  <svg id="vis" width="100" height="20">
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="99" height="19" />
    <line x1="50" y1="20" x2="50" y2="0" style="stroke:red;opacity:0.7" />
    <line id="visSlope" x1="50" y1="20" x2="50" y2="0" />
  </svg></p>

  <p><label>Combining Filter</label><br/>
  <select id="combine-select">
    <option value="atop" selected="selected">Composite atop</option>
    <option value="over">Composite over</option>
    <option value="blend">Blend normal</option>
    <option value="merge">Merge</option>
    <option value="none">none</option>
  </select></p>
</div>

<pre></pre>
```

The same external on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ccprog/full/jaRGze/).

I am so far aware of these rendering errors:

- filtering HTML objects seems not to be supported in Safari, Edge and IE
- ColorMatrix seems to be buggy in Chrome when applied to SVG objects
- ColorMatrix and  Component/linear have been reported to be buggy in Firefox 57/Windows

I have not seen all of these errors, so feel free to add to this list or correct it.

Related post: [SVG feGaussianBlur and feColorMatrix filters not working in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219364/svg-fegaussianblur-and-fecolormatrix-filters-not-working-in-chrome)